# How to add SWT plugins eclipse luna

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

I imported my eclipse plugin project in to eclipse luna.

In project all plugins are showing compile time error. Error is org.eclipse.swt is missing.

Eclipse luna has only org.eclipse.e4.swt plugin.

how to import org.eclipse.swt plugin in eclipse luna?

Please help me.

Note : My project developed in eclipse helios IDE.

following MAINFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: %Bundle-Name.0
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.chinna.cim.smash;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 4.0.2
Bundle-Activator: com.chinna.cim.smash.SMASHPlugin
Bundle-Vendor: %Bundle-Vendor.0
Bundle-Localization: plugin
Eclipse-ExtensibleAPI: true
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.core.resources,
 org.eclipse.ui.ide,
 org.eclipse.ui.forms,
 org.eclipse.ui.editors,
 org.eclipse.jface.text,
 com.ami.megarac.utils
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Bundle-ClassPath: patch.jar,
```

com.ami.megrac.utils manifest file

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Utils Plug-in
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.ami.megarac.utils;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 4.0.2
Bundle-Activator: com.ami.megarac.utils.UtilsPlugin
Bundle-Vendor: American Megatrends Inc
Eclipse-ExtensibleAPI: true
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.core.filesystem,
 org.eclipse.ui.console,
 org.eclipse.core.resources,
 org.eclipse.core.resources,
 google.api.translate,
 org.eclipse.ui.forms,
 com.ami.megarac.MegaRACDevStudio,
 org.eclipse.ui.ide,
 org.eclipse.jface.text,
 org.eclipse.ui.editors,
 org.eclipse.cdt.core,
 org.eclipse.compare
Export-Package: com.ami.megarac.utils,
 com.ami.megarac.utils.cdt,
 com.ami.megarac.utils.console,
 com.ami.megarac.utils.copyright,
 com.ami.megarac.utils.file,
 com.ami.megarac.utils.filesystem,
 com.ami.megarac.utils.ini.parser,
 com.ami.megarac.utils.ini.texteditor,
 com.ami.megarac.utils.jobs,
 com.ami.megarac.utils.localize,
 com.ami.megarac.utils.localize.actions;
  uses:="com.ami.megarac.utils.localize.wizards,
   org.eclipse.jface.operation,
   org.eclipse.core.runtime,
   org.eclipse.ui,
   org.eclipse.jface.action,
   com.ami.megarac.utils.localize.model,
   org.eclipse.core.resources,
   org.eclipse.jface.viewers,
   org.eclipse.swt.widgets",
 com.ami.megarac.utils.localize.builder;
  uses:="org.eclipse.core.runtime,
   com.ami.megarac.utils.localize.model,
   org.eclipse.core.resources,
   org.eclipse.swt.widgets,
   org.w3c.dom,
   org.xml.sax.helpers,
   org.xml.sax",
 com.ami.megarac.utils.localize.dialogs,
 com.ami.megarac.utils.localize.model,
 com.ami.megarac.utils.localize.wizards,
 com.ami.megarac.utils.mapmodel,
 com.ami.megarac.utils.mvc,
 com.ami.megarac.utils.resources,
 com.ami.megarac.utils.resources.compare,
 com.ami.megarac.utils.translator,
 com.ami.megarac.utils.translator.input,
 com.ami.megarac.utils.ui.forms.custom,
 com.ami.megarac.utils.ui.forms.events,
 com.ami.megarac.utils.ui.forms.model,
 com.ami.megarac.utils.ui.forms.part,
 com.ami.megarac.utils.ui.forms.part.controls,
 com.ami.megarac.utils.ui.forms.transfer,
 com.ami.megarac.utils.xml,
 com.memetix.mst,
 jboolexpr,
 org.json,
 org.json.simple,
 org.json.simple.parser
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Bundle-ClassPath: patch.jar,
 lib/microsoft-translator-java-api-0.6.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar,
 .,
 lib/jboolexpr-1.2.jar,
 lib/org.json.jar
```

Comment: All versions of Eclipse have the org.eclipse.swt plugin, it is absolutely fundamental to the working of Eclipse. Have you included it in the plugin dependencies?

Comment: yeah i tried to include in plugin dependencies. there in search org.eclipse.swt is not available.

Comment: I agree all version eclipse will have org.eclipse.swt. then why my class is showing org.eclipse.swt is unresolved.

Comment: You won't see it in the Add list if it is already included directly or indirectly (for example having org.eclipse.ui in the list automatically includes it). `org.eclipse.swt` on its own is not a valid import - show us the exact error message and code.

Comment: The import org.eclipse.swt.SWT cannot be resolved this error i am getting

Comment: swt is there but i am not able to load any objects under the swt package

Comment: The actual SWT classes are in the platform dependent SWT fragment plugin, for example on macOS they are in `org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64`. Are you perhaps using a 'target platform' for a different architecture?

Comment: how to check that?

Comment: Have you version ranges specified in _META-INF/MANIFEST.MF_?

Comment: What do you have set in the Preferences under 'Plug-in Development > Target Platform'? Also edit your question and show us your MANIFEST.MF.

Comment: i have added my manifest file in question

Comment: Maybe some version restrictions in the *MANIFEST.MF* of `com.ami.megarac.utils`?

Comment: i have added the utils manifest as well

Comment: If it has nothing to do with versions, maybe in your target platform some plug-ins are missing: _Window > Preferences: Plug-in Development > Target Platform_ (Did you imported the project into a new workspace?)